# Access forbidden! in LAMPP

Tags: php, ubuntu, permissions, phpmyadmin, lampp

[image]I install LAMPP in system 15.05 ubuntu opt folder and after I type localhost/dashboard it show home page but i need to put .php file on opt/lampp/htdocs but it can have permission.
After that i user this link [Fixpermisson](http://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/ubuntu-12-04-tips-and-tricks/how-to-fix-permission-of-htdocs-in-ubuntu.html).

```
 #
        # This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
        # configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
        # See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/> for detailed information.
        # In particular, see 
        # <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/directives.html>
        # for a discussion of each configuration directive.
        #
        # Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
        # what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
        # consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
        #
        # Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
        # of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
        # server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
        # with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so 'log/access_log'
        # with ServerRoot set to '/www' will be interpreted by the
        # server as '/www/log/access_log', where as '/log/access_log' will be
        # interpreted as '/log/access_log'.

        #
        # ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
        # configuration, error, and log files are kept.
        #
        # Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
        # ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to specify a local disk on the
        # Mutex directive, if file-based mutexes are used.  If you wish to share the
        # same ServerRoot for multiple httpd daemons, you will need to change at
        # least PidFile.
        #
        ServerRoot "/opt/lampp"

        # 
        # Mutex: Allows you to set the mutex mechanism and mutex file directory
        # for individual mutexes, or change the global defaults
        # 
        # Uncomment and change the directory if mutexes are file-based and the default
        # mutex file directory is not on a local disk or is not appropriate for some
        # other reason.
        #
        # Mutex default:logs

        #
        # Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
        # ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
        # directive.
        #
        # Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
        # prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
        #
        #Listen 12.34.56.78:80
        Listen 80

        #
        # Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
        #
        # To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
        # have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
        # directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
        # Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
        # to be loaded here.
        #
        # Example:
        # LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
        #
        LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
        LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
        LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
        LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
        LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
        LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
        LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
        LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
        LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
        LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
        LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
        LoadModule authz_dbd_module modules/mod_authz_dbd.so
        LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
        LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
        LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
        LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
        LoadModule auth_form_module modules/mod_auth_form.so
        LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
        LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
        LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
        LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
        LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
        LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
        LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
        LoadModule socache_memcache_module modules/mod_socache_memcache.so
        LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
        LoadModule bucketeer_module modules/mod_bucketeer.so
        LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
        LoadModule echo_module modules/mod_echo.so
        LoadModule case_filter_module modules/mod_case_filter.so
        LoadModule case_filter_in_module modules/mod_case_filter_in.so
        LoadModule buffer_module modules/mod_buffer.so
        LoadModule ratelimit_module modules/mod_ratelimit.so
        LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
        LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
        LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so
        LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
        LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
        LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
        LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so
        LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
        LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
        LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
        LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
        LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
        LoadModule log_debug_module modules/mod_log_debug.so
        LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
        LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
        LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
        LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
        LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
        LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
        LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
        LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
        LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
        LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
        LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
        LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
        LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
        LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
        LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
        LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
        LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
        LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
        LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
        LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so
        LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
        LoadModule session_cookie_module modules/mod_session_cookie.so
        LoadModule session_dbd_module modules/mod_session_dbd.so
        LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
        LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
        LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
        LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
        LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
        LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module modules/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
        LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
        LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
        LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
        LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
        LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
        LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so
        LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
        LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
        LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
        LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
        LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
        LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
        LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
        LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
        LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
        LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
        LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

        <IfDefine JUSTTOMAKEAPXSHAPPY>
        LoadModule php4_module        modules/libphp4.so
        LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
        </IfDefine>

        <IfModule unixd_module>
        #
        # If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
        # httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
        #
        # User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
        # It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
        # running httpd, as with most system services.
        #
        User nobody
        Group nogroup
        </IfModule>

        # 'Main' server configuration
        #
        # The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
        # server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
        # <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
        # any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
        #
        # All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
        # in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
        # virtual host being defined.
        #

        #
        # ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
        # e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
        # as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
        #
        ServerAdmin you@example.com

        #
        # ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
        # This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
        # it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
        #
        # If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
        #
        #ServerName www.example.com:@@Port@@
        # XAMPP
        ServerName localhost

        #
        # Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
        # explicitly permit access to web content directories in other
        # <Directory> blocks below.
        #
        <Directory />
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

        #
        # Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
        # particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
        # you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
        # below.
        #

        # 
        # DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
        # documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
        # symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
        #
        DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"
        <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs">
            #
            # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
            # or any combination of:
             Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
            #
            # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
            # doesn't give it to you.
            #
            # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
            # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#options
            # for more information.
            #
            #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            # XAMPP
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes

            #
            # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
            # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
            Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
            #
            #AllowOverride None
            # since XAMPP 1.4:
            AllowOverride All

            #
            # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
            #
            Require all granted
            Options All

        </Directory>

        #
        # DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
        # is requested.
        #
        <IfModule dir_module>
            #DirectoryIndex index.html
            # XAMPP
            DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.php index.php3 index.php4
        </IfModule>

        #
        # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
        # viewed by Web clients. 
        #
        <Files ".ht*">
            Require all granted
        </Files>

        #
        # ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
        # If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
        # container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
        # logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
        # container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
        #
        ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

        #
        # LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        #
        LogLevel warn

        <IfModule log_config_module>
            #
            # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
            # a CustomLog directive (see below).
            #
            LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
            LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

            <IfModule logio_module>
              # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
              LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
            </IfModule>

            #
            # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
            # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
            # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
            # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
            # logged therein and *not* in this file.
            #
            CustomLog "logs/access_log" common

            #
            # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
            # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
            #
            #CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule alias_module>
            #
            # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
            # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
            # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
            # Example:
            # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar

            #
            # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
            # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
            # Example:
            # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
            #
            # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
            # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
            # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
            # the filesystem path.

            #
            # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
            # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
            # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
            # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
            # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
            # directives as to Alias.
            #
            ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/opt/lampp/cgi-bin/"

        </IfModule>

        <IfModule cgid_module>
            #
            # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
            # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
            #
            #Scriptsock logs/cgisock
        </IfModule>

        #
        # "/opt/lampp/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
        # CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
        #
        <Directory "/opt/lampp/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options None
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <IfModule mime_module>
            #
            # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
            # filename extension to MIME-type.
            #
            TypesConfig etc/mime.types

            #
            # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
            # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
            #
            #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
            #
            # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
            # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
            #
            #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
            #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
            #
            # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
            # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
            #
            AddType application/x-compress .Z
            AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

            #
            # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
            # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
            # or added with the Action directive (see below)
            #
            # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
            # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
            #
            #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
            # XAMPP, since LAMPP 0.9.8:
            AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl

            # For type maps (negotiated resources):
            #AddHandler type-map var

            #
            # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
            #
            # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
            # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
            #
            # XAMPP
            AddType text/html .shtml
            AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
        </IfModule>

        #
        # The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
        # contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
        # directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
        #
        #MIMEMagicFile etc/magic

        #
        # Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
        # 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
        #
        # Some examples:
        #ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
        #ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
        #ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
        #ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
        #

        #
        # MaxRanges: Maximum number of Ranges in a request before
        # returning the entire resource, or one of the special
        # values 'default', 'none' or 'unlimited'.
        # Default setting is to accept 200 Ranges.
        #MaxRanges unlimited

        #
        # EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
        # memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall may be used to deliver
        # files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
        # be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
        # filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
        # broken on your system.
        # Defaults: EnableMMAP On, EnableSendfile Off
        #
        EnableMMAP off
        EnableSendfile off

        # Supplemental configuration
        #
        # The configuration files in the etc/extra/ directory can be 
        # included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of 
        # the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as 
        # necessary.

        # Server-pool management (MPM specific)
        #Include etc/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

        # Multi-language error messages
        Include etc/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

        # Fancy directory listings
        Include etc/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

        # Language settings
        #Include etc/extra/httpd-languages.conf

        # User home directories
        #Include etc/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

        # Real-time info on requests and configuration
        #Include etc/extra/httpd-info.conf

        # Virtual hosts
        #Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

        # Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
        #Include etc/extra/httpd-manual.conf

        # Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
        #Include etc/extra/httpd-dav.conf

        # Various default settings
        Include etc/extra/httpd-default.conf

        # Configure mod_proxy_html to understand HTML4/XHTML1
        <IfModule proxy_html_module>
        Include etc/extra/proxy-html.conf
        </IfModule>

        # Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
        <IfModule ssl_module>
        # XAMPP
        <IfDefine SSL>
        Include etc/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
        </IfDefine>
        </IfModule>
        #
        # Note: The following must must be present to support
        #       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
        #       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
        #
        <IfModule ssl_module>
        SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
        SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
        </IfModule>

        # XAMPP
        Include etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf
        Include "/opt/lampp/apache2/conf/httpd.conf"
```

Comment: In my index.php file ->
  Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-(

Answer (score 3):

This is a permission issue, run the following command from your terminal

```
sudo chmod -R 0755 /opt/lampp/
```

Comment: Thank you it work but can you explain little bit more.

Comment: The problem was the directory /opt/lamp/ was protected by file permission. When you added the file permission to execute then it's working. Read more there  http://www.pageresource.com/cgirec/chmod.htm

Comment: @Khoshed Hey Still have trouble with.

Comment: Yes still did not acess database?